# Java Files behaviour on Jenkins

Tags: java, file-io, jenkins, junit

I am running into problems on my (Linux) Jenkins server when using the Java [Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) API.

An integration test is failing, which uses a JUnit `TemporaryFolder`. The test executes the following code:

```
Path expectedPath = tmpFolder.getRoot().toPath().resolve("folder1/folder2");

// create files

assertTrue(Files.exists(expectedPath.resolve("newFile1.txt")));
```

The test passes locally, and I see in the logs for the Jenkins run that `expectedPath` is being created successfully, but what confuses me is the "path" to my new file:

```
/tmp/junit0219318729037123/folder1\/folder2/newFile1.txt
```

Why has `\/` been introduced? Is this some quirk of Files on Linux, or a problem with my `tmpFolder`?

Comment: Can you show us how you create the new file ? It looks like `newFile1.txt` is in a folder named `folder1/folder2` and not in the `folder2` (which is in `folder1`)

Comment: When creating the file, I use `Files.createDirectories` to create folder1 and  folder2, I then use `Files.write(myFilePath, someBytes, StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW, StandardOpenOption.WRITE`.

Comment: Obviously a problem is with programmatic file or folder creation. Could you provide us a full piece of code where you create file.

Comment: Please note that the code to write files / create directories is generic and is used successfully by several other integration tests, all of which pass.